# Eclipse - Android - Add "Imports"

Tags: eclipse

Coming from .NET background ...

Is there a way to either via key stroke or by automatic settings to have the "Import" statements added that are needed by the code?

Right now I have to right click each class that I am referencing and choose the add option to have the Imports added and that's slow. I'd like to do them all at once with a single key stroke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that SHIFT COMMAND O does the job.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Helios with Android extension, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> works for this purpose.

You can see what you particular key binding is by going to *Window->Preferences->General->Keys* and enter "import" in the filter widget. Look for "Add import" in the search results.

If it is bound to a key sequence, you can use (or change ) that sequence. If it is not
bound, you can bind it to a key sequence.

Answer (score 0):

[image] + SHIFT + O for mac users.  Had me stuck for a bit but works.